# Opening popup window from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and hence stuck at a very simple point. I am trying to open a popup window from an existing browser window using below code :

```
string url = "D13.aspx";
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

D13.aspx is an empty aspx page. There are no console errors or popup getting blocked. But the popup window is not opening up.
Is there anything to be done in javscript or this code alone is enough? Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no reason this should not work. Is this code being executed within your Page_Load event? What does your markup look like?

Comment: Is D13.aspx in the same path of the aspx page from where you are triggering this?

Comment: @Cal279: The code is executed while user clicks on a button

Comment: @SouvikGhosh : No. D13 is the new popup aspx page i want to open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your browser blocks pop-up enable popup in your browser then run it, will work fine..
I have checked it with chrome. you your chrome is blocking that at right hand side of window corner there will be a red alert showing that popup blocked you can allow from there...

Comment: Sorry. no popups are blocked

Answer (score 2):

I have tested the below and found that it works (IE 11):

```
protected void OpenPopUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "D13.aspx";
    string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Button Text="Open PopUp" OnClick="OpenPopUp_Click" runat="server" />
```